# How can I quickly clear GPT partition data from a disk?

Tags: linux, gpt

I want to do a quick "wipe" of some disks so they look like they're ready to be newly partitioned.  Currently there is a GPT partition type on disk, which seems to write some data both at the beginning and end of the disk.  In this case, it doesn't matter if the data on the disk is wiped, so no need to wait for the *whole* disk to dd from /dev/zero. So what's a simple way to clear just the beginning and end GPT headers?

In this case, I'm using Linux (CentOS 7) with standard SATA disks (/dev/sda, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it pretty efficiently, based on the [information about GPT on this site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#About_the_GUID_Partition_Table).

Clear the first block (two 512-byte sectors for MBR and header, and 16KiB for partition entries):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdwhatever bs=512 count=34
```

The last part is trickier.  I'm borrowing from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/wipe-last-1mb-of-a-hard-drive) to assist, although if you have ddrescue handy, [it can go in reverse](https://superuser.com/questions/347029/reading-from-the-end-of-a-drive-with-dd).

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdwhatever bs=512 count=34 seek=$((`blockdev --getsz /dev/sda` - 34))
```

Comment: The reason this is so helpful is that all the commands (`dd`, `blockdev` ... uh that's it) are available in RHEL's `initrd.img` which means they're guaranteed to be available in the Anaconda/kickstart `%pre` environment. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

`gdisk` has an option for it. Open extended options, choose 'zap':

```
gdisk /dev/sda
> x
> z
> w (maybe?)
```

Comment: TIL, the gdisk Zap option!  This will be my preferred method when only doing one or two disks.

Comment: This looks a simpler option than what I posted, assuming you have gdisk available.

Answer (score 2):

FreeBSD utility `gpart` can do it in this pretty straightforward way:

```
gpart destroy -F /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Should this be `gparted` instead of `gpart`?  I didn't find a `gpart` command installed by default, and there's no RPM in the regular CentOS repos.

Comment: Sorry, `gpart` is a FreeBSD tool for managing GPT. I was sure linux have it too.